# cannot set up H2 JPA database witih Spring Boot - error : no bean available to autowire

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, autowired, spring-repositories

I followed the tutorial on Building a REST API with spring boot. https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/rest/

Everything is fine until when I try to set up a `@Configuration` to set up h2 database connectivity.

I have a repository

```
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {}
```

I have an @Entity :

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
    private @Id @GeneratedValue Long id;
    private String name;
    private String role;

    public Employee() {}
}
```

and of course I have my @SpringBootApplication

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class RestdemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(RestdemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

The error I am getting is in the LoadDatabase @Configuration class :

[image]

Why would there be an error when I followed the tutorial exactly?  Is the tutorial missing some key step or annotation, or did I goof up somewhere?

Comment: You didn't show package statements, so what happens if you mark your interface as `public`? Also, you didn't show your build file; are you including `spring-boot-starter-data-jpa`? Finally, IDEs are fallible; did you try _running_ the application?

Answer (score 0):

Your repository class needs to be annotationed with `@Repository` so it can be registered as a bean inside the Spring Application Context:

```
@Repository
public interface EmployeeRepository extends JpaRepository<Employee, Long> {}
```

Also, the error in your screenshot is an IDE error, trying to predict a runtime exception on boot. In some cases, it might be a false positive.

Comment: Your answer is not correct; `@Repository` is not required on Spring Data repository interfaces.